# An sql query that is already work well on hosting, but not work on WAMP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query that is already work well on hosting, but not on WAMP I get SQL error 1064, Please help. 
Thanks!

```
$query = 'SELECT p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_ordered, IF (s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price, p.products_price, pd.products_name, p.products_model';


    if ( defined('FEATURED_MODUL_SPECIALS_ONLY') AND FEATURED_MODUL_SPECIALS_ONLY == 'true' ) {
            $query .= 'FROM ' . TABLE_SPECIALS . ' s LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p ON s.products_id = p.products_id ';
    } else {
            $query .= 'FROM ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_SPECIALS . ' s ON p.products_id = s.products_id ';
    }
    if ($current_page != FILENAME_DEFAULT)  { 
        $query .= 'LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id AND pd.language_id = '" . $languages_id . "'
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_FEATURED . " f ON p.products_id = f.products_id
        WHERE p.products_status = '1' AND f.status = '1' order by rand($mtm) DESC limit " . FEATURED_MODUL_MAX_DISPLAY;
    }else{
        $query .= 'LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id AND pd.language_id = '" . $languages_id . "'
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_FEATURED . " f ON p.products_id = f.products_id
        WHERE p.products_status = '1' AND f.status = '1' order by rand($mtm) DESC limit " . FEATURED_MODUL_MAX_DISPLAY_FIRST_PAGE;
    }
```

and I got error on WAMP server:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id LEFT JOIN products_descr' at line 1

SELECT p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_ordered, IF (s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price, p.products_price, pd.products_name, p.products_modelFROM products p LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id LEFT JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id AND pd.language_id = '1' LEFT JOIN featured f ON p.products_id = f.products_id WHERE p.products_status = '1' AND f.status = '1' order by rand(12852) DESC limit 12

[TEP STOP]

Comment: Maybe you have a different version of MySQL server on your local machine?

Comment: you don't have a space before your `FROM` in your generated statement. Try adding a space before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the query would have ever worked as written.  The first string is:

```
'SELECT p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_ordered, IF (s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price, p.products_price, pd.products_name, p.products_model'
```

Then the second is one of:

```
'FROM ' . TABLE_SPECIALS . ' s LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p ON s.products_id = p.products_id '
```

or

```
'FROM ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_SPECIALS . ' s ON p.products_id = s.products_id '
```

In both of these, the `select` list would look like:

```
'p.process_modelFROM '
```

I doubt that is a column in the table.  And I suspect the query is missing a `from` clause as well.

Put the space back at the end of the `select` line and the query should work.

The specific error you are getting is happening during the first pass of the compiler.  It is finding the key words `left join`, but they are not in a `from` clause.